# AWS Site-to-Site VPN- Local/remote ipv4 cidr mandatory?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-vpn

[image]

I am creating a site-to-site vpn to make a request from aws to my on premises.
Here, is the screenshot(AWS Console) of a VPN connection that I created. My question is:
Is it mandatory to assign local ipv4 and remote ipv4 network cidr or I can just keep 0.0.0.0/0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, it is `0.0.0.0/0` as it states under your AWS Console when you are trying to create a connection.

[image: aws-vpn-s2s-network-cidr-optional]

I believe that it is optional, to be more secure, you should only input *a fixed network range* that you would like to **maintain the least privileges access** from on-premise and vice versa.